# Making profit using OpenCV?

Tags: licensing, ios, bsd-license, image-processing

I was looking to use OpenCV to program an image recognition app for iOS. One thing I wanted to check is if I were to charge $0.99 or $1.99 for the app, would I be breaking OpenCV's license? I didn't see anything in the license regarding this.

Comment: rather blatant duplicate of [Can I use new BSD licensed library/code in commercial closed source project?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/165418/can-i-use-new-bsd-licensed-library-code-in-commercial-closed-source-project)

Answer (score 4):

The [About Page](http://opencv.org/about.html) says:

> OpenCV was built to provide a common infrastructure for computer vision applications and to accelerate the use of machine perception in the commercial products. Being a BSD-licensed product, OpenCV makes it easy for businesses to utilize and modify the code.

In addition, the [license](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/LICENSE) is the standard 3-clause BSD license, which is one of the more permissive licenses out there, and often used by projects which want their code to be used in commercial projects.

While there's no substitute for having a lawyer provide legal advice, this license is commonly understood to allow commercial use in basically any way as long as you present the copyright notice in any source or binary distributions.

Answer (score -1):

As the original author (and not a lawyer): Yes, you can use it commercially. Somewhere in the source code (if you redistribute source whether modified or not) you must retain the original BSD license, or if you just include it in your binary, you must provide users a pointer to your use of OpenCV and its BSD license here: https://opencv.org/license/

The intent of OpenCV.org was/is to provide a common infrastructure for R&D AND to promote the beneficial commercial use of the library whether free or for profit. Go for it guys, gals and others!

Comment: "As the original author" considering opencv has had many authors, and your username is anonymous, this claim needs some substantiation.